# What do you call a person who is favoring someone else

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who is favoring someone? 
For instance if your employer favors your co-worker over yourself, you would refer to your employer as what?

Comment: Playing favorites.

Comment: Do you want an adjective or a noun? Can you give an example sentence with a blank space? Please read the guidelines for [single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and edit your question to make sure it has all of the information people will need to write good answers.

Comment: he is *partial* (as opposed to *impartial*)

Answer (score 3):

***Biased*** may be what you want.

> **Biased:** showing an ​unreasonable ​preference or ​dislike ​based on ​personal ​opinion.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/biased)

Answer (score 2):

**Favoritism:**

> 1: the showing of special favor : PARTIALITY
>
> 2: the state or fact of being a favorite
>
> [[Merriam Webster Dictionary]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/favoritism)

Comment: favoritism is the action but the question is about a name for the person who is doing that action.

Answer (score 1):

***Nepotism*** can be used if favoring relatives.

> **Nepotism:** the ​activity of ​unfairly giving good ​jobs or ​advantages to ​members of ​your ​family.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/nepotism)

***Partisan*** can be used for supporting any person.

> **Partisan:** a strong supporter of a party, cause, or person.
>
> [[Dictionary.com]](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/partisan)

Comment: And note that *nepotic* is an adjective for practicing nepotism.

Comment: [Synonyms for nepotism](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nepotism), many of which can apply to non-family favoritism.